# InnoDB locking: what does index record mean?

Tags: mysql, index, locking

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-next-key-locks)

> Record Locks
>
> A record lock is a lock on an index record.

1. what does `index record` mean for cluster index?
2. what does `index record` mean for secondary index?
3. Is it a `key-value` pair in the B+ tree leaf node?
4. Is it a data struct in MySQL source code?

### Reference

This article seems useful, but I just don't understand.

https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/btree-index-structures-in-innodb/

https://github.com/octachrome/innodb-locks

Comment: One of the indexes in InnoDB is clustered one. ALWAYS (if no unique indices in DDL this clustered index is autogenerated and hidden). See [Clustered and Secondary Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html). The key value for this clustered index is hiddenly added to any another index. The 'record index' mentioned in citate is the record's index key exactly by this clustered index. Any operation which alters data always detects the record in a table (record's physical place in table's storage file) exactly by this index.

Comment: By questions. 1) The clustered index expression value for a record. 2) The clustered index expression value for a record which is hiddenly included to secondary index expression value. 3) No, except this index is first unique one (if primary exists it is first always). 4) No.

Comment: A record is another word for row. An index record, is a row of an index table. Every time you create a table, there will be another datastructure representing the index. In InnoDB the index is stored in a tree (B+Tree).